# How to add fullcalendar in google site

Tags: node.js, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have created a google site in which I would like to add fulcalendar.io. However I don't have any background of scripting or coding.

Can someone guide me in steps how exactly it can be added in google site?

Do I need scripting knowledge or simply it will be importing the files or adding it as a gadget, kindly help?

I have tried to go through [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) website and searched google. I have also tried to directly add html code in google calendar but that didn't help.

Can I please get steps to add the fullcalendar in google site.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some code. [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks for response... i downloaded node.js application....then created a project in google api ...created credentials for 0auth...enabbled google calender api ...downloaded the json file ....also tested this is connectivity in google app script ... later tested the connectivity of my calender from node.js command prompt ...i could see the my calender entries displayed in command prompt of node.js and logs of google app scipt...but i dont know how to go forward now ..and how to embed fullcalender in my google site

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this official decription](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/)? Furthermore I found this [git repo](https://github.com/MikeSmithDev/FullCalModal-Node) what can be useful for you. ;)

Comment: Hi yes I tried official description from API and made it work //but unable to understand whats the next step to get the calender added in my site/....you can say i  am complete novice and doesnt have any programming background..any step by step help to add this fullcalender in my site is apperciated

Comment: I see. Have you added a `<div id='calendar'></div>` element to your html file? :)